# IIS Express won't start all services in VS 2015

Tags: android, wcf, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I am developing an Android App that uses a WCF DataService. I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2015.  I had been using Visual Studio 2013 and this was working fine. The default services in my case are set up for localhost with http = port 52842 and https = 44300.  I am using an Android Device to debug so it would not be able to get to the data service through the localhost designation.  I added a third entry to facilitate external connections to the data service.  My applicationhost.config is as follows

```
    <site name="MyDataService" id="9">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\Dev\Mobile\MyDataService" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52842:localhost" />
            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44301:mycomputer.mydomain.com" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
```

When I was using VS2013 and went to debug, all 3 services started up.  Now that I am on VS2015, only the first two start.  If I exit VS and run the following command, all three services start:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IISExpress\IISExpress /site:MyDataService
```

Is there a way to get VS2015 to start all three as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the hidden .vs/config/applicationHost.config under the solution folder and you will see why.

VS2015 uses this file instead of the global one.

Comment: It worked great.  Is there any condition where it might overwrite this file in the future now that I have it set up correctly?

Comment: @JimWilcox no guarantee.